# How to hide the seperator at the top of the first cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm customizing a Tableview ..

I want to hide the top seperator line separating on the first cell. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure TableView with no Separators, and then add custom image at the bottom of every cell which will look same as separator, so you can achieve this functionality.

Comment: agreed, simply create a line on the bottom of the cell and use it as a seperator

Comment: I'd like to do this without an image. Can I somehow create a colored subview instead?

Comment: It will create a problem for grouped cell as well.

Comment: Grouped cells does not have top separator on first cell, so there is no problem. @totaliratian yes you can add subview, but you will need first to inspect actual separator color, you can use Color Measure mac utility for this.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has

```
@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor               *separatorColor;
```

So try this

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

or

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And after that you should customize all of your cells with your own separators.
Simply add view with autoresizing mask **flexible top margin** and **flexible width**
Don't forget to add it to `cell.contentView`
Actual color of separator is `[UIColor grayColor];`

Comment: I belive he's asking for just the first cell. `seperatorColor` is for the entire tableView

Comment: Fixed post due to suggestion.